# What would this contour look like in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm currently trying to visualise what the contour $\gamma (t) = te^{4 \pi i t}$ (for $0 \leq t \leq 1$) would look like in the complex plane. I would imagine that it would be a spiral, twice anti-clockwise starting at the origin, but I am not sure.

Is my intuition correct? If not, what should this look like and how can I better understand/visualise contours like this before attempting to sketch them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a spiral starting in the origin, winding around it exactly two times. You could plot the parametric version for a better visualization:

$$\vec x(t)=\begin{pmatrix}t \cos(4\pi t) \\ t \sin(4\pi t)\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure why $f(0) \neq 0$ - since the coefficient of the exponential term is $t$?

Comment: The parametric equation is correct, but I do believe $\vec x(t=0) = \vec 0$ because $t$ multiplies the trig functions. @DCooper: I think your original intuition is correct.

Comment: Of course! My fault. I fix it

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @M.Winter's answer, here is a graphic of the parametric equations:
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x(t) &= t \cos(4\pi t) \\
y(t) &= t \sin(4\pi t)
\end{aligned} \right.
$$
[image]

An [Archimedean Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral).